# momentjs find difference and display in specific format

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, datetime-format

I have from datetime displaying

```
2019-12-19 06:00
```

I have to datetime displaying

```
2019-12-19 09:22
```

I am using moment.js. I need to find the difference of these two time and should have to display in this format

```
3H, 55M
```

This is what i have tried

```
moment(date1).diff(moment(date2), 'hours') "," moment(date1).diff(moment(date2), 'minutes')
```

and i am not getting the proper format with difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out just getting difference between two dates in minutes and then converting to hours and minutes.

```
var date1= moment('2019-12-19 06:00')
var date2 = moment('2019-12-19 09:22')

var diffInMin=moment.duration(date2.diff(date1)).asMinutes()
var hours = Math.floor(diffInMin / 60) + 'H'
var minutes = diffInMin % 60 + 'M'
console.log(hours +', '+ minutes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like this:

```
moment(moment(toDate).diff(moment(fromDate))).format('HH[H] mm[M]')
```